# Do all townies share the locker?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

This little locker is awesome, multiple pages of items and three areas to store things in.. But is this shared with other people who live in my town? IE: If I make a second character and move them into town, do they get their own locker inventory or do they share mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locker inventory is unique player to player according to [this forum thread](http://www.axaforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=80&t=55245).

Comment: I can confirm this from personal experience.